# how to set up many users to use the same imap account. Dovecot, Roundcube

Tags: imap, postfix, dovecot, roundcube

to be more specific, i will describe my problem.
I have to install local IMAP server (Dovecot) that will download messages via pop3 from info@myextmail.com (with Fetchmail).
To use Dovecote locally i chose roundcube, because of its design and ease of use.
To send email, i need to use external smtp server, and i chose Postfix.
Locally i have 5 users. user1, user2....
I would like that every user could login into roundcube, but all should use same imap INBOX folder. When user1 reply to a message, everyone should see this message as 'replied' and can check it in SENT folder. 
But i would like also that every user can create his own set of filters, virtual folders. So that on main account messages would stay always in INBOX folder, but every user can create virtual folder an copy/link there messages.
Also when sending a message i would need to set a signature like 'send by User1, Company Co.', and other users would see that in SENT, replied messages.

I hope i made it clear. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is it possible. As described in the documentation http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes